# How to use a text dataset that is al ready tokenized at character level?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, tokenize, seq2seq

I have a text dataset that contains already tokenized text, at character level with characters separated by space, space replaced by _ and unknown characters replaced by a #. The goal is to use this dataset to train a seq2seq or transformer model for correcting spellings. I am having trouble using this dataset. I am unclear on how to feed this dataset to the model. Do I have to add the [start] and [end] tags to the target sentences on the already tokenized text? How do I build the vocabulary as previously I would preprocess the text myself and have only done word level tokenization. I have tried hard but haven't been able to find much useful information. If you guys can direct me to the right material/tutorial I would really appreciate that. I am very new to deep learning for NLP.

Comment: If you want to use transformers try looking at the [tutorials](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/1?fw=pt) they offer and maybe the pretrained `imvladikon/general_character_bert` model. You can also use the opennmt library ([tutorial here](https://opennmt.net/OpenNMT-py/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the HuggingFace pre-trained model or use Tensorflow-Keras to train your seq2seq model.
With Tensorflow, the steps should be :

1. Add a start and end token to each sentence.
2. Clean the sentences by removing special characters.
3. Create a word index and reverse word index (dictionaries mapping from word → id and id → word).
4. Pad each sentence to a maximum length.

The ready to use code is available as mentioned in the [Notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/tutorials/nmt_with_attention.ipynb) here.

You can directly use the tokenized dataset with this model.